# Ext Js How to Pass Params to Server Code

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel

I've got two Ext GridPanels and want to pass an OrderID value from my Orders store to my PHP server code  As I look through the docs, I see params, baseparams and beforeload listeners as possible ways to achieve this. The code below seemed straight forward but my param doesn't seem to get passed.

```
    OrdersGrid.on('rowclick', function(grid, rowIndex, e) {
    var selectedRecord = this.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
    var val = selectedRecord.get('OrderID');
    ItemsDataStore.load( {params : {OrderID: val }});
    });
```

Any ideas on how to debug this appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the baseParams on the store:

```
ItemsDataStore.baseParams.OrderID = val;
ItemsDataStore.load();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added ItemsDataStore.baseParams.OrderID = val; to my listener along with ItemsDataStore.load(); but it doesn't seem to work for me. Did i misunderstand?